Acceder a un hostvirtual local desde un móvil
Muy buenas a todos.
Resulta que estoy haciendo una web. La estoy haciendo en local, y he creado un virtualhost para emular al servidor y en lugar de usar localhost/miweb utilizo miweb.test.
Resulta que quiero accedes desde mi móvil. Puedo acceder con la url 192.168.100.120/www/miweb, pero hay una página que extrae parte de la url, entonces no es lo mismo miweb.test que 192.168.100.120/www/miweb entonces cuando quiero coger un dato en una url por ejemplo miweb.test/dato en el virtualhost no tengo problema pero cuando accedo del móvil si ya que en 192.168.100.120/www/miweb/dato me coge www en lugar de dato.
Mi pregunta es la siguiente ¿es posible desde móvil acceder desde el navegador como miweb.test en luegar de 192.168.100.120/www/miweb?
Un saludo y gracias por leerme y vuestro tiempo de antemano.

Como posible, lo es.

Supongo que hay diversas formas de hacerlo. Desde usar un proxy "trucado" para que resuelva miweb.test, o bien, si tienes un servidor DNS en casa (no el router, sino uno propio), jugar con el para que lo resuelva hacia la IP deseada.  Entiendo que quieres hacerlo desde la propia wifi, pues de forma externa sería más complejo al tener que exponer tu localhost públicamente de algún modo, etc... Ninguna de estas formas es fácil, a menos que el movil tenga un archivo "hosts" que se pueda toquetear y entonces sí que con una linea lo arreglas, pero no tengo ni idea de como chuta ni android ni iphone

Por otro lado, seguramente lo más sencillo será cambiar tu código para que empiece a contar la ruta desde el final, en lugar desde el principio, y de ahí sacar los elementos que desees, pues esos si que serian invariables en ambos casos.

He leído lo de cambiar el archivo host en android, tendría que buscar la manera de editarlo como root y probar. Lo que no se me había ocurrido es lo de leer la ruta al revés. Lo intento a ver. Muchas gracias por la idea.
